# Issue when adding NULLS LAST

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpql

When adding "NULLS LAST" on the following query I'm getting the exception below:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 11.

1. If I remove the NULLS LAST everything works fine
2. If I remove the CASE WHEN code and order by just one specific column it works with the NULLS LAST, but I need all the columns on the CASE WHEN.

```
    @Query("SELECT c FROM ClassSpecificationTableEntity c"
            + " LEFT JOIN c.owner  o "
            + " LEFT JOIN c.domain d "
            + "WHERE ISNULL(c.classStructure.classification.description, '')    LIKE :SEARCH "
            + "   OR ISNULL(c.classStructure.description, '')                       LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(d.description, '')                                            LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(o.description, '')                                            LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(c.measurementUnit, '')                                    LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(c.defaultValue, '')                                       LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(c.dataType, '')                                               LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " OR ISNULL(c.tooltip, '')                                                LIKE :SEARCH "
            + " ORDER BY "
            + "  CASE :ORDERBY" + 
            "    WHEN 0 THEN c.classStructure.classification.description " +
            "    WHEN 1 THEN c.assetAttribId " + 
            "    WHEN 2 THEN c.dataType " + 
            "    WHEN 3 THEN c.measurementUnit " + 
            "    WHEN 4 THEN c.domain.description " + 
            "    WHEN 5 THEN c.owner.description " + 
            "    WHEN 6 THEN c.defaultValue " + 
            "    WHEN 7 THEN c.tooltip " + 
            "    END DESC NULLS LAST" 
            )
    Page<ClassSpecificationTableEntity> findByLikeSearchDESC(@Param(value="SEARCH") final String searchCrit, final Pageable pageable, @Param(value="ORDERBY") final String orderBy);
```

Comment: Where are your `ON` clauses?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `NULLS LAST` syntax is T-SQL.

If you want to order `NULL` values last the common way is to use a `CASE` expression or `IIF`:

```sql
--CASE Expression
CASE WHEN {expression} IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
--IIF funciton (which is actually a shorthand CASE expression)
IIF({Expression} IS NULL, 1, 0)
```

---

If you have a complicated expression, that you want to order the `NULL` values last for, and then the expression, and that expression does not appear in the `SELECT` (so cannot be referenced by its Alias), then you can move the expression to the `FROM`, to avoid typing the expression multiple times:

```
FROM ...
     JOIN ...
     LEFT JOIN ...
     ...
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES({Expression}))V(Alias)
WHERE ...
ORDER BY IIF(V.Alias IS NULL,1,0),
         V.Alias
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is: Having in mind all what you have said, how do I rewrite my query in JPQL so the correct T-SQL can be generated?